# How to have scrolling animation programmatically

Tags: android, animation, gallery

I'm trying to implement scroll animation for gallery programmatically.

Tried with `setSelection(int pos, Boolean animate)` and it's not working.

Is there anyway to override `setSelection()` method.

Answer (score 12):

Just now I have got this problem. I was need to move just one element of the gallery, so the best solution to me was to emulate key down event

```
myGallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
```

or

```
myGallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

Gallery.setSelection(int position, boolean animate);

Refer below URL:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9140fd6af3061cdf/7f89e53ae53e455b?lnk=gst&q=setselection#7f89e53ae53e455b

Soln:
If you're still looking, I have two possible solutions for you, both
slightly unpleasant:

(1) You can make the gallery do a fling with a chosen velocity, thus:

myGallery.onFling(null, null, velocity, 0);

By tweaking the velocity, you can set up values to move the selection
by one or two in either direction. As the Gallery self-centers, you do
not need to get the destination exactly right.

(2) As the Gallery source is available, you can modify it in order to
implement your own Gallery. It doesn't look as though you need to add
much code to be able to control a fling so as to end at your chosen
selection.

I thought I was going to have to do (2), but found I could get away
with (1) for my problem.

Comment: Method (1) works great, just make sure you use a sufficiently large velocity. Shame the Android docs here are so misleading: "Notified of a fling event when it occurs" is incorrect IMHO, should say something like: "Tells the Gallery to perform a fling" or the method should be called performFling

Answer (score 6):

Based on Kurru's excellent thinking of simulating clicking next or previous view.

```
//scroll forward or backward
private void scroll(int type){
    View selectedV = mG.getSelectedView();
    int idx = mG.indexOfChild(selectedV);
    switch(type){
        case FORWARD:
    default:
        if(idx<mG.getChildCount()-1)
            idx++;
        break;
    case BACKWARD:
        if(idx>0)
            idx--;          
        break;
    }
    //now scrolled view's child idx in gallery is gotten
    View nextView = mG.getChildAt(idx);
    //(x,y) in scrolled view is gotten
    int x = nextView.getLeft()+nextView.getWidth()/2;
    int y = nextView.getTop()+nextView.getHeight()/2;
    String out = String.format("x=%d, y=%d", x, y);
    Log.i(TAG+".scroll", out);

    //Kurru's simulating clicking view
    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(100, 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    mG.onDown(event); 
    boolean res = mG.onSingleTapUp(null);
    Log.i(TAG+".scroll", "onSingleTapUp return =" + res);       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking through the Gallery source to see if I could get this feature. It looks like something is possible with this code. However I gave up before I could get it working. It seems like I wasn't passing in the correct coordinates so res always returned false. Would return true if it worked.

Just posting this here in-case someone else wants to give a go at fixing it! (Please post your solution if you manage it!)

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
gallery.getHitRect(rect);


int x = rect.centerX()+getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int y = rect.centerY();

MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(100, 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
timesGallery.onDown(event);
boolean res = timesGallery.onSingleTapUp(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I made little change in code given by "Kurru". this is working now

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
    gallery.getHitRect(rect);

    int width = Math.abs(rect.width());
    if(!isForwardScroll){
        width = width * -1;
    }
    int x = rect.centerX()+width/2;
    int y = rect.centerY();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(100, 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    gallery.onDown(event);
    boolean res = gallery.onSingleTapUp(null);
```